# Profile:Edit Logout link not working

Tags: profile-edit, bug, mightybigrobot

I just updated to the latest EE, CT and P:E on sunday. Everything's working great so far but I found to have one problem: the logout link for logged in users doesn't work.

The code:

```
{if logged_in}
        {exp:profile:view}<a href="{path='account'}">Hallo {member_first_name} {member_last_name}</a>{/exp:profile:view} • <a href="{exp:profile:logout_link return="/"}">Logout</a>                        
{if:elseif logged_out}
[...]
```

When clicking the logout link on the frontpage the page refreshes but I am still logged in.

I have tried as superadmin and regular user both with the same behaviour.

I searched here and on the Forums but it seems like I am the only person having this problem... :/

Any ideas on this?

Thanks and Cheers,

Marc

Comment: have you tried {if logged_in} ... {if:else} {/if} as the value will only ever be true or false

Comment: Thanks Steven, I just tried that but it still doesn't work. I have contacted MBR via Twitter about this issue. They recommended using the native EE {path='logout'} link, which works but redirects to the standard EE member notification page, which is okay but I'd still rather have a return="/somewhere" param. I'll contact them again and see if there is a possible fix available in the meantime.

Comment: perhaps look at using the custom system messages addon in that case, you'll be able to style that better

Comment: I'm can confirm this as well :(

Comment: Well, I guess there won't be a quick fix for this from MBR since they took Profile:Edit out of their sales pipeline for now. Not saying that it won't ever be fixed just not atm.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue (EE 2.8.1) and solved this by modifying the logout link to:

```
<a href="{path='?ACT=109'}&XID={XID_HASH}" role="button">logout</a>
```

You'll find the correct action_ID (ACT) for the profile:edit logout, in the exp_actions table.

Comment: Thanks user2986, at least this takes care of the (in my opinion) unnecessary logout confirmation screen. Still I am missing a logout redirect param as this simply goes to /index.php in every case which is okay, but ultimately I would like to just keep the logged out user on the page where he last was.